# Easier way to update MySQL row based on previous data?

Tags: php, mysql

I was wondering if there was an easier way to go about updating data in my MySQL database. I have a column called "food" which is an integer.

Whenever I want to update the amount of food, I have to SELECT the current amount, create a new variable for $new_food which is the current food count + amount of food to add. Then I have to run the UPDATE query to shove $new_food in.

This seems pretty inefficient. Is there an easier way to go about updating my food column?

Comment: Post more information about your schema. You *should* be able to do a straight `UPDATE`. But you have mentioned some calculations that may not make it that simple.

Comment: Pretty basic, single column table. 1 row containing food count.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can increase column directly in `UPDATE` query:

```
UPDATE tbl_name SET col_name = col_name + 123 WHERE ...;
```

Answer (score 3):

`UPDATE` queries have access to the previous value of the column.

```
UPDATE sometable SET food=food+:morefood WHERE id=:someid
```